# Creating an instance without requiring a newtype dummy

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Lets say I have the following:

```
class C a where
  f :: a -> Blah  

f_impl_for_d :: D a => a -> Blah
f_impl_for_d = _ 

newtype Alice f a = Alice (f a)
```

And maybe some existing instances like so:

```
instance C a => C [a] where ...
instance C a => C (Identity a) where ... 
instance C a => C (Maybe a) where ...
```

What I want is an instance *like* this:

```
instance (D a, C a => C (f a)) => C (Alice f a)
```

As in, wherever `D a` is valid, and there's an instance `C (f a)` with the constraint `C a`, then I should be able to derive `C (Alice f a)`

For example, if I have `D a`, then I should have `C (Alice [] a)`, and `C (Alice Maybe a)` etc.

Now I could do this:

```
instance D a => C a where
  f = f_impl_for_d

instance C (f a) => C (Alice f a) where
  f (Alice x) = f x
```

But that top instance is rediculously overlapping.

Any other way? The only way I've worked out is to make a newtype like so:

```
newtype T x = T x

instance D x => C (T x) where
  f (T x) = f_impl_for_d x

instance (Functor f, C (f (T x))) => C (Alice f x) where 
  f (Alice x) = f (T <$> x)
```

But that seems somewhat convoluted. Any nicer way? I tried mucking around with quantified constraints but I didn't get far.

Comment: I can't see if what you want is `instance (D a, forall b . C b => C (f b)) => C (Alice f a)` after turning on the `QuantifiedConstraints` extension.

Comment: @chi I think so but then whats the implementation?

Comment: I think I now understand the issue more clearly. I can't find any solution which is better than your newtype one. The issue is that you really need to prove something like `forall a. D a => C a` but that can't be done without the overlapping instance -- if that were possible otherwise, coherence could be broken I think. Perhaps another option you could try is redefining D as `class C a => D a where ...` (?) That doesn't look to be very convenient, though.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want the newtype dummy? It looks quite the right tool for the job to me.

Comment: @leftaroundabout if it's the right tool for the job I'll use it. It just seemed a bit obtuse. But it does the job.

Answer (score 5):

`C a => C (f a)` isn't quite what you need. You might think of it as a function `C a -> C (f a)` but its meaning is technically a bit more refined than that: the `C a` constraint can only be solved using instances; that function cannot take arbitrary arguments.

You can define a (kind of) subclass which provides such a function instead:

```
class (forall a. C a => C (f a)) => C1 f where
  f1 :: (a -> Blah) -> (f a -> Blah)
```

Which then must be implemented explicitly, for example `Maybe`, using your current implementation of `C a => C (Maybe a)`, and that `C` instance can be replaced with a default `f1 f`.

```
instance C1 Maybe where ...
instance C a => C (Maybe a) where
  f = f1 f
```

Then you can have

```
instance (D a, C1 f) => C (Alice f a) where
  f (Alice x) = f1 f_impl_for_d x
```

This is similar to the `Eq1`, `Ord1`, `Show1` classes in base. The initial intent was to encode a quantified constraint `(forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a))` (before they were a thing), but technically these classes are slightly more expressive than that because the constraint `Eq a` (which identifies a globally unique value) is replaced with a type (which may have many values).